# How to add different tooltips using title for <line/> in svg

Tags: html, svg

I am working with a svg element and I want to assign different `title` to different svg `<line>`. For example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      </link>
      <svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1280 720">
         <line class="upper clone" x1="10" y1="0" x2="220" y2="0" style="stroke:rgb(110, 31, 194);stroke-width:1" />
         <title>original upper location (10,0)</title>
         <line class="lower clone" x1="10" y1="260" x2="220" y2="260" style="stroke:rgb(218, 149, 22);stroke-width:1" />
         <title>original lower location (10,260)</title>
         <rect x="40" y="50" width="80" height="100" fill="#007bbf">
            <title>A blue box</title>
         </rect>
         <rect x="180" y="50" width="80" height="100" fill="#ec008c">
            <title>A pink box</title>
         </rect>
      </svg>
      <!--<script src="index.js"></script>-->
      <script src="index2.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, it only shows the same tooltip for both the lines, whereas it is different for `rect`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the `<line>` and `<title>` tags with a  group tag

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      </link>
      <svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1280 720">
         <g>
         <line class="upper clone" x1="10" y1="0" x2="220" y2="0" style="stroke:rgb(110, 31, 194);stroke-width:4;cursor:pointer" />
            <title>original upper location (10,0)</title>
         </g> 
        <g> 
         <line class="lower clone" x1="10" y1="260" x2="220" y2="260" style="stroke:rgb(218, 149, 22);stroke-width:2;cursor:pointer" />
         
           <title>original lower location (10,260)</title>
        </g> 
        <g>
         <rect x="40" y="50" width="80" height="100" fill="#007bbf" cursor="pointer"/>
              
          <title>A blue box</title>
        </g>
    <g> 
         <rect x="180" y="50" width="80" height="100" fill="#ec008c" cursor="pointer"/>
            <title>A pink box</title>
    </g>        
      </svg>
      <!--<script src="index.js"></script>-->
      <script src="index2.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

### Update

`<title>` cannot be nested in base svg shape tags For example: `line` `rect` `path`

Comment: Thanks for this but I want to avoid grouping unless absolutely required.

Comment: @smpa01 Without the `<g>` tag, it will be impossible for svg to understand which element the tooltip refers to. See addendum above in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that but I can see the other answer is perfectly working. Is it kindly possible for you to give an example of when the accepted answer will fail so that I can understand your point of view? I do want to understand it as I am at the beginning of development and want to get it correct now rather than later at an advanced development stage when I get stuck with my own mistake.

Comment: @smpa01 The answer above breaks SVG syntax. In svg tags for basic shapes: rect, line, path, etc. you can't nest other SVG tags. For example - `<title>`. If you want your application to work equally correctly in all browsers, then you should not violate the w3C syntax for svg

Comment: @Alexandr_TT: I totally agree with your approach but it's actually standard compliant to nest "meta-like" elements like `title` or `desc` within an otherwise self-contained svg element like `<path>`, `<rect>`, `<circle>`, `<line>` etc.
[Excerpts from the W3 Specs](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/struct.html#DescriptionAndTitleElements) "  
Any container element or graphics element in an SVG document can have zero or more ‘desc’ and/or ‘title’ elements as children, whose content is text. ‘desc’ and ‘title’ elements are not visually rendered as part of the graphics."

Comment: @Alexandr_TT: pardon me, character limit:  
Backing up your approach (also from the specs): 
"Authors should use grouping (‘g’) elements to structure their drawing elements into meaningful objects, and name those groups with ‘title’."

Answer (score 2):

You insert the `<title>` element inside the two `<line>` elements like how a `<div>` works:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      </link>
      <svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1280 720">
         <line class="upper clone" x1="10" y1="0" x2="220" y2="0" style="stroke:rgb(110, 31, 194);stroke-width:1">
           <title>original upper location (10,0)</title>
         </line>
         <line class="lower clone" x1="10" y1="260" x2="220" y2="260" style="stroke:rgb(218, 149, 22);stroke-width:1">
           <title>original lower location (10,260)</title>
         </line>
         <rect x="40" y="50" width="80" height="100" fill="#007bbf">
            <title>A blue box</title>
         </rect>
         <rect x="180" y="50" width="80" height="100" fill="#ec008c">
            <title>A pink box</title>
         </rect>
      </svg>
      <!--<script src="index.js"></script>-->
      <script src="index2.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

A simple but effective solution.

**Note:** You may want to get the cursor to just the right position to see the tooltips.

Comment: you are right (upvoted). But It might be slightly misleading to compare svg elements' behavior to divs ;) (e.g. regarding auto growing, text-wrapping etc.)    
Apart from meta-like elements like `<title>` , `<desc>` or style related elements like `<animate>`  – svg (shape) elements shouldn't be nested (albeit, there might be other exceptions ...).